# Specifying the Mean and Variance in a Scipy Distribution Python 2.7

Tags: python-2.7, scipy, distribution

I need to randomly sample from some distribution eventually, so I need one that allows me to readily change the mean and variance. I'm looking at using distributions from the scipy.stats library, however, I'm having difficulty seeing how the parameters "loc" and "scale" relate to the quantites I'm interested in. I'd like to be able to do something like:

```
x = numpy.linspace(0,5,1000)
y = scipy.stats.maxwell(x, mean, variance)
```

But loc and scale seem to be the only other arguments that function takes.
Can anyone specify the relationship those quantities must have to mean and variance, or suggest a better library to use?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I don't have python 2.7, so answer would be for python 3.6, but it should work, it is a scipy after all.

Basically, you have to extract `scale` and `loc` parameters from given `μ` and `σ`. Here are two simple functions to do that, plus some sampling to prove we're getting right values. Basically, first printed line is what you want, and third line is result of sampling, should be roughly be the same. Second line is `scale` and `loc`computed from `μ` and `σ`. Play with the numbers, see how it is going

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import maxwell

def get_scale_from_sigma(sigma):
    """Compute scale from sigma based upon http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MaxwellDistribution.html"""
    a2 = np.pi*sigma / (3.0*np.pi - 8.0)
    return np.sqrt(a2)

def get_loc_from_mu_sigma(mu, sigma):
    """Compute loc from mu/sigma based upon http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MaxwellDistribution.html"""
    scale = get_scale_from_sigma(sigma)
    loc = mu - 2.0 * scale * np.sqrt(2.0 / np.pi)
    return loc

sigma = 1.0
mu    = 2.0 * get_scale_from_sigma(sigma) * np.sqrt(2.0 / np.pi) # + 3.0 as shift, for exampl
print(mu, sigma)

scale = get_scale_from_sigma(sigma)
loc   = get_loc_from_mu_sigma(mu, sigma)

print(scale, loc)

q = maxwell.rvs(size=10000, scale = scale, loc = loc)
print(np.mean(q), np.std(q))
```